# ¿Como cambiar icono de las tres rayitas del Navegation Drawer en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, icons

He logrado cambiar el icono del toolbar de los tres punto pero no se donde cambiar el icono mencionado de las tres rayas
[image: Foto del icono a cambiar]

Answer (score 0):

¿Como cambiar icono de Navigation Drawer?

Si tienes agregado un DrawerLayout, obten el Toolbar y configura otra imagen desde tus recurros usando `setNavigationIcon()` :

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_other_icon);
```

Comment: juste probé con eso pero no entiendo porque no se cambia, cabe destacar que he utilizado la configuración por defecto del Android Studio al crear el Navigation Drawer Activity, ahora voy a probar a crear de 0 el menu a ver si funciona